# Is the "know" in "Do you know" an infinitive?

Tags: infinitives, auxiliary-verbs, present-simple

Is the **know** in the sentence *"Do you **know** where the mall is?"* classified as a (bare) infinitive?

Is seems to, because the construction seems to be **auxiliary verb + infinitive**, much like "can know" or "would know", but the auxiliary verb is not modal, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, in interrogatives like your example the tense (here, present) is marked on auxiliary "do" and the lexical verb is the plain (infinitive) form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  In clauses with a auxillary verb, you will get a verb in one of the unchanging forms, either a past participle "have known", a present participle "is knowing" or the base form of the verb, also called the bare infinitive "do know".